# Issue with opening SQLite Database file in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

Does anyone know how to open a sqlite database in windows mobile 6.5(emulator)? I have tried to use the following code to open it, but it has no success. It says "Unable to open the database".

```
private SQLiteConnection con;

public void OpenDB(){

con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings................\Data\iPhysioMobile");

con.open();

}
```

I have used to use the full path of the database file. Does anyone know why it occurs? or any other suggestions?

Regards,

SW Lau

Answer (score 0):

No wonder this code is not working.

The path is invalid. There is no such drive as C:\ in windows mobile.

Location `("C:\Documents and Settings................\Data\iPhysioMobile")` shared by your computer and windows mobile is from computer point of view not windows mobile.

To know folder in windows mobile from where your app is running, use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`. Then open .db file from that location.